# Pancake Flipping: Recursive Python

Tags: python, recursion

I'm having a terrible time coming up with an algorithm to flip a "stack" of pancakes,which are really a list of numbers. You're allowed to flip the top at a certain index and above. Even something in pseudo code would be a rolling start, if you don't want to do full Python. i just have trouble with recursion. Not sure if base case should be `pancakes.is_in_order() == True` or something more like `len(pancakes) == 1: return pancakes`.

Input example: pancakes = [2,3,1,4]    (Top here would be 2. You can flip pancakes[:index] by doing a reverse() on that slice of list)

Need to flip such that you have [1,2,3,4]

Output: # of flips it takes (don't need to show flips, order, etc. Just number of flips. If it's over a dozen, then timing out is fine)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by flip the stack?

Comment: Is this a sorting algorithm?

Comment: Are you looking for the length of the shortest flip sequence?

Comment: Does it have to be recursive? Because there's a really good and easy solution that is not in fact recursive

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it does. I too can write up the iterative pretty well, but I am being forced to use recursion. I have ran through a decent number of lines of code experimenting, but I can't seem to get the idea. Thus, I didn't want to splatter the page with one of the dozen versions I have tried. I keep changing it every minute or so.